# Finding all cities within a specific radius using HERE API: limitations and alternatives

Tags: here-api

I'm interested in finding all the cities within a specific radius (x km) from a central city, based on given coordinates. I've tried using the following GET request with the HERE Reverse Geocoding API:

```
GET https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/
    revgeocode
    ?at=50.1158056,8.6786751
    &types=city
    &apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

However, the API only returns the city corresponding to my input coordinates, rather than providing a list of all nearby cities. I'm looking for alternative approaches to achieve my initial objective.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "in=circle" parameter along with the radius and provide the limit(Maximum number of results to be returned), by default the limit is 1 so you are getting only 1 result.
For example:
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?in=circle:50.1158056,8.6786751;r=50000&types=city&limit=10&apiKey=Your_Api_Key

Radius in here is in meters and the response will show 10 results as we have the limit set to 10.

Hope that helps.